# django rest framework- how can I pass query params to foreign key serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For my application, I have Locations, and Events given by the following (simplified) models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Event(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    date = models.DateField()
```

In my API, I have an endpoint: `/api/locations/` which returns all locations, and each location has its events embedded within it, e.g.:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Location 1',
        'events': [
            {'id': 1, 'date': '2018-01-01'},
            {'id': 2, 'date': '2018-01-14'}
        ]
     },
     {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Location 2',
        'events': [
            {'id': 3, 'date': '2017-12-28'},
            {'id': 4, 'date': '2018-01-10'}
        ]
     }
]
```

my serializers look like:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'date',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = EventSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'events',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Using ViewSets, I would like to add a filter to this call, with a `max_date`, and `min_date` parameter, e.g.: `/api/locations/?min_date=2018-01-01&max_date=2018-01-15`.  Which should return only locations that have events between those two dates, AND should only return the events for each location between those two dates.

In the example data above, both locations would return, Location 1 would have both events listed, but Location 2 would only have the second event in its list.  In my ViewSet, I can take those parameters and append them as queryset filters:

```
class LocationViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        min_date = self.request.query_params.get('min_date', None)
        max_date = self.request.query_params.get('max_date', None)
        if min_date is not None and max_date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(event__date__lte=max_date, event__date__gte=min_date)
        return queryset
```

Which will filter out any locations that do not have any events between the two dates, however those returned locations show ALL of their events, not just the ones between `min_date` and `max_date`.  I assume I have to somehow pass my query parameters on to the `EventSerializer` embedded within `LocationSerializer`, but am unsure as to how I might do this.

Comment: Is your filtering process reflected on `queryset`  variable? (take `len(queryset)` to cross check )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to prefetch filtered events in view:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
class LocationViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
serializer_class = LocationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        min_date = self.request.query_params.get('min_date', None)
        max_date = self.request.query_params.get('max_date', None)
        if min_date is not None and max_date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(event__date__lte=max_date, event__date__gte=min_date).prefetch_related(Prefetch('events', queryset=Event.objects.filter(date__lte=max_date, date__gte=min_date))
        return queryset
```

Also you can use [`serializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to filter events:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'events',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    get_events(self, obj):
        min_date = self.context['request'].query_params.get('min_date', None)
        max_date = self.context['request'].query_params.get('max_date', None)
        events = obj.events.filter(date__lte=max_date, date__gte=min_date) 
        return LocationSerializer(events, many=True).data
```

With `self.context['request']` you can get request data inside serializer.

Comment: `self.context['request']` was the missing link. I used the `serializerMethodField` example and it worked great.  I like the idea of applying the filter within the serializer, as I may be doing similar filters elsewhere on the location.  Any thought on if one or the other method is more scalable?

Comment: @MarkD If you have any other customized filters, probably it would be better to use `serializerMethodField`.

Comment: okay my problem is also the same but i am not able to get the response as expected... tried both prefetch and SerializerMethodField but still unable to get a response

Comment: But how do you validate that `min_date` and `max_date` are valid data? In the case of passing primary key as query param, it will cause an 500 error if a string is passed instead of integer.